# Java: wait for ActionEvent

Tags: java, swing, events, methods

I want to make a method wait until an ActionEvent method has processed before continuing.
Example:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    someBoolean = false;

}
```

the actionPerformed method is linked to a textField I have, and the method is triggered when you press Enter. What I want to do, is have a different method pause until the actionPerformed method happens.
Example:

```
public void method() {

    System.out.println("stuff is happening");
    //pause here until actionPerformed happens
    System.out.println("You pressed enter!");

}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why all these fancy gymnastics? Why not simply have two methods, one called from a constructor or other event, and the other called from the JTextField's ActionListener?

Comment: It looks like you are waiting for the user to enter data in a text field. So why don't you display a JOptionPane to ask the user to enter the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) should do the trick. You want to create a latch waiting for 1 signal.

Inside the actionPerformed you want to call countDown() and inside "method" you just wanting to await().

-edit-
I'm assuming that you've already got the right amount of Threads set up to handle the situation.

Comment: The link you posted is outdated, here is the current API for CountDownLatch: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: hahaha, thanks. It was the first one to come back from google. Must remember to put Java 7 in the search in the future.

Comment: *"Must remember to put Java 7 in the search in the future."*  You might also vote for this [RFE](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875), so we can always link to the 'latest' JavaDocs (and the link will remain stable).

Comment: [OT] @Andrew Thompson would have, but voting is not as easy as expexted (in fact, currently impossible - for me only?) https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2310897&tstart=15

Comment: @kleopatra I see what you mean.  After only 6 minutes I managed to log in to the bug DB, but when I went to reply to your post on OTN there were those idiot *"500 Internal Server Error"* messages.  :(

Comment: [OT] @Andrew Thompson 'after _only_ 6 minutes' - you are the patient type :-) Curious, with which credentials, old sun or new oracle?

Comment: Old credentials.  And no, I'm not patient.  Many tabs open, probably refreshed the SO `java` tag once or twice and looked over a few posts in that time (in between wasting time playing Peggle levels).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways and CountDownLatch is one of them. Another way it to use a Semaphore which is reusable.

```
private Semaphore semaphore = Semaphore(0);
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    semaphore.release();
}
public void method() {
    System.out.println("stuff is happening");
    semaphore.acquire();
    System.out.println("You pressed enter!");
}
```

Also you should think about the sequences of what is happening. If the user hits enter more than once should that be counted more than once. And also if it is possible for an action event to come in after the waiting method acquires it. You might do the following:

```
private Semaphore semaphore = Semaphore(0);
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if ( semaphore.availablePermits() == 0 ) // only count one event
        semaphore.release();
}
public void method() {
    semaphore.drainPermits(); // reset the semaphore
     // this stuff possibly enables some control that will enable the event to occur
    System.out.println("stuff is happening");
    semaphore.acquire();
    System.out.println("You pressed enter!");
}
```